# Operands Could not be Broadcast with Shapes (19,)(0,) -- KNN

Tags: numpy, error-handling, ipython, classification, knn

I am working on how to use KNN to predict a rating for a movie. I use a video and a book to teach myself how to go about it

I tried to run the code I found in the book but it gave me error message. I googled the error message so as to understand it and fix my problem but I don't think I know how to adapt the solutions to my problem.

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

r_cols = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating']

ratings = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', engine='python', names=r_cols, usecols=range(3))  # please enter your file path here. The file is u.data

print(ratings.head())   

movieProperties = ratings.groupby('movie_id').agg({'rating': [np.size, np.mean]})

print(movieProperties.head())

movieNumRatings = pd.DataFrame(movieProperties['rating']['size'])

movieNormalizedNumRatings = movieNumRatings.apply(lambda x: (x - np.min(x)) / (np.max(x) - np.min(x)))

print(movieNormalizedNumRatings.head())

movieDict = {}

with open('C:/Users/dell/Downloads/DataScience/DataScience-Python3/ml-100k/u.item') as f:     # The file is u.item

    temp = ''

    for line in f:

        fields = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')

        movieID = int(fields[0])

        name = fields[1]

        genres = fields[5:25]

        genres = map(int, genres)

        movieDict[movieID] = (name, genres, movieNormalizedNumRatings.loc[movieID].get('size'), movieProperties.loc[movieID].rating.get('mean'))

print(movieDict[1])

from scipy import spatial

def ComputeDistance(a, b):

    genresA = np.array(list(a[1]))

    genresB = np.array(list(b[1]))

    genreDistance = spatial.distance.cosine(genresA, genresB)

    popularityA = np.array(a[2])

    popularityB = np.array(b[2])

    popularityDistance = abs(popularityA - popularityB)

    return genreDistance + popularityDistance 

print(ComputeDistance(movieDict[2], movieDict[4])) 

import operator

def getNeighbors(movieID, K):

    distances = []

    for movie in movieDict:

        if (movie != movieID):

            dist = ComputeDistance(movieDict[movieID], movieDict[movie])

            distances.append((movie, dist))

    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    neighbors = []

    for x in range(K):

        neighbors.append(distance[x][0])

    return neighbors

K = 10

avgRating = 0

neighbors = getNeighbors(1, K)
```

**I got this error message from PowerShell:**

Traceback(most recent call last):

```
neighbors = getNeighbors(1, K)

dist = ComputeDistance(movieDict[movieID], movieDict[movie])

genreDistance = spatial.distance.cosine(genresA, genresB)

return correlation(u, v, w=w, centered=False)

uv = np.average(u*v, weights=w)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (19,)(0,)
```

**I got this error message when I tried to debug the problem from ipython terminal:**

```
c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py(695)correlation()

     693        u = u - umu

     694        v = v - vmu

---> 695        uv = np.average(u*v, weights=w)

     696        uu = np.average(np.square(u), weights=w)

     697        vv = np.average(np.square(v), weights=w)


**Note**: The code ran fine and produced results up until *print(Cprint(ComputeDistance(movieDict[2], movieDict[4]))*

My guess is the problem is with this part of the code: 


import operator
def getNeighbors(movieID, K):
    distances = []
    for movie in movieDict:
        if (movie != movieID):
            dist = ComputeDistance(movieDict[movieID], movieDict[movie])
            distances.append((movie, dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(K):
        neighbors.append(distance[x][0])
    return neighbors

K = 10
avgRating = 0
neighbors = getNeighbors(1, K) 


The code can be found in this link: https://hendra-herviawan.github.io/Movie-Recommendation-based-on-KNN-K-Nearest-Neighbors.html
```

Comment: Do you understand the error?  That comes before finding a fix.  Working back through the traceback can take some work, but it's a good guess that there are size problems in the `cosine` arguments, `genresA`, `genresB`.  Have you checked them?  Their `type`, and if arrays, `shape` and `dtype` are a starting point.

Comment: Please clean up your code. Body wants to treat that much to debug your program. And you unnecessarily duplicated all newlines, too.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I just added the link where the code can be found. Also, for the purpose of education, I will appreciate it if you can suggest to me the materials to use to learn how to clean up a code

Comment: @hpaulj i thought as much but the code ran well until I imported the operator module. I have edited the question and included a link where you could find the code online. Also, when I tried to determine the shape or size of genresA using genresA.size etc, I got an error message saying genresA was not defined.

Comment: See the help site: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The error of "operands could not be broadcast together with shape (x,)(y,)" usually raises when you are trying to perform an operation between two arrays that must have the same shape but they don't. In your case you are trying to take an weighted average between two arrays u and v. The arrays u and v don't have the length.

I saw that you parsing a movies list by splitting the lines with the "|" character and then storing these results in a dictionary. Probably this file or its division with "|" are returning different results.

The error log shows that the second array doesn't have any element, this could be generated by an empty line on the movies files.

Comment: I think the error has to do with the latter part of the code as the code ran well up until I called the operator module. I have edited the question though

Comment: Then why don't you drop the operator module and try to the same without (which is trivial to do)? Or you just delete anything from "import operator" onward, and I'd assume the error still is there (hence it cannot be due to import operator)... If you would clean up your code and make a MWE, then you would likely already find the issue yourself...